# I want to create procedure to affect many rows

Tags: sql-server

My table consist of start time, time till now , end time columns so i want to calculate the time till now for all rows by subtracting now time by start time but it affects only one row, I want to affect all rows.

code:

```
create procedure timetillnow
declare @starttime time,
@nowtime time,
@diff time

select @starttime = starttime from schedule
select @nowtime = GETDATE()

select @diff = DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@starttime,@nowtime)

update schedule set timetillnow = @diff
```

Comment: Let me ask this, are you trying to create a stored procedure that will simply Update the TimeTillNow column?

Comment: yes calculate time till now for each row and update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it in a single update statement without a `where` clause:

```
update schedule set timetillnow = DATEDIFF(MINUTE,starttime,getdate())
```

This will update every row in the table.

Comment: this updates timetillnow column with the same value , i want it to update each row with its value from the calculation

Comment: No it doesn't: try it.